# Formvalidation.io dynamic rule

Tags: javascript, validation, formvalidation.io

I am using formvalidation.io to validate a simple form. However, I would like to enable the notEmpty validator only if the value of a global field equals to 1.

For example in the code below I would like to validate the email field but enable the third validator only if the value of a global variable emailrequired is equal to 1.

I do not want to write my own validator for this as this example occurs many times for different fields and I need a global solution.

```
email: {
            validators: {

                stringLength: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 50,
                  },
                regexp: {
                        regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
                         },
                notEmpty: {
                      message: 'Field is required'
                  },

            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to each validator, for example:

> enabled: emailrequired==1